# Taking records from a column, and inserting them into one row in Access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I'm working with a file in my Access database that has a list of charges in one column, but I would like to spread those charges across multiple different columns, but keep them all in the same row. The current setup looks like this:

```
      --type---------------Amount----
        Previous            1234.50
        Current             3456.54 
        Adjustments         123.00
     --------------------------------
```

I'm trying to move these charges to another table that is set up where the field headings are the different types from the first table. I'm trying to achieve this end result:

```
   ----Previous---------Current-------Adjustments---
        1234.50         3456.54       1123.00
   -------------------------------------------------
```

I've tried running a query where it inserts each amount if the type ="Previous" AND "Current" AND "Adjustments" but obviously, this doesn't give the desired results because it will only pull the amount over if that amounts type = all three types, which is never the case. How could I go about getting the results I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Havent tested it or anything but play around with something like this. Im assuming that there is something like CustomerID that those 3 rows relate to.

```
TRANSFORM SUM(Amount)
SELECT CustomerID, Type, Amount 
FROM CurrentData 
GROUP BY customerID
PIVOT Type;
```

Comment: Wouldn't this rename the Field headings each time I need to run this query? Sorry, I'm really unfamiliar with Pivot.

Comment: @user1781966 - it should use the values from the type column as column headings

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO AnotherTable (Previous, Current, Adjustments)
SELECT TOP 1 (SELECT TOP 1 Amount FROM OriginalTable WHERE type = 'Previous') AS Previous,
(SELECT TOP 1 Amount FROM OriginalTable WHERE type = 'Current') AS Current,
(SELECT TOP 1 Amount FROM OriginalTable WHERE type = 'Adjustments') AS Adjustments
FROM OriginalTable
```

Comment: The example you provided is returning an error where it says "Number of query values and destination fields are not the same"